# Help With Renaming Files With Uploadify

Tags: php, database, file, upload

This is my code -

```
<?php
session_start();
include('connect.php');
mysqli_select_db($connect, "users");
$s = "select * from name where sessionusername = '$u'";
$q = mysqli_query($connect, $s);
$f = mysqli_fetch_array($q);
$name = $f['name'];

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // $fileTypes  = str_replace('*.','',$_REQUEST['fileext']);
    // $fileTypes  = str_replace(';','|',$fileTypes);
    // $typesArray = split('\|',$fileTypes);
    // $fileParts  = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    // if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$typesArray)) {
        // Uncomment the following line if you want to make the directory if it doesn't exist
        // mkdir(str_replace('//','/',$targetPath), 0755, true);
        // Get the extension, and build the file name
     //$extension = pathinfo($tempFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
     $extension = end(explode(".",$_FILES['Filedata']["name"])); 
     $new_file_name =  '".$name."'".".$extension;

    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $new_file_name;
    // $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];




        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        echo str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$targetFile);
    // } else {
    //  echo 'Invalid file type.';
    // }
}
```

?>

Why is the above not working? As you can see, I am trying to pull down the name from the users database, and then rename the uploaded file to the name that was pulled from the db.

Can you help me out? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What part is not working?  Is there an error being generated?  Is the file actually being uploaded or is it empty?

Comment: the file is not getting uploaded. error HTTP_ERROR.

Comment: Please copy the exact error message.

Comment: Make sure your form has the correct enctype (multipart/form-data)

Answer (score 1):

Is form enctype == 'multipart/form-data' ?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, now I understand what you're talking about. You should remove your other post. This is an error I've actually encountered with Uploadify before, but I'm not sure what is going on here, specifically. Definitely, checkout your enctype, but for debugging, I implemented this solution for error reporting with Uploadify here: http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/14/upload-script-error-reporting/p1.